# Using a puppet/facter fact in a Foreman smart class parameter?

Tags: ruby, puppet, theforeman, facter

How can I use a puppet/facter fact like ${$::hostname} in a Foreman smart class parameter?

I've tried $hostname and $::hostname and just about every variant I can think of! I've even trawled through Google and Foreman docs and bug reports. Surely there's a simple answer?

Answer (score 1):

It's an old question, but you use facts like you do in a ERB template, example:

`<%= @host.shortname %>`

would get you xyz of xyz.example.com

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your answer. How to get the FQDN of a host? `<%= @fqdn %>` returns an empty string, and I cannot find any documentation where you got the shortname from, I cannot find it in any fact documentation. Edit: Found the documentation.